# BSONDocument.getAs issue

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have 1 problem and 1 question when using BSONDocument getAs.

Whenever I try to access the value l in the format below by calling this:

```
docFound.getAs[Int]("v.1.0.2013.9.9.l")
```

it returns None. However if I do:

```
docFound.getAs[BSONDocument]("v")
```

it returtns a valid BSONDocument for the whole v section. What is wrong in my first call? Does reactivemongo support path traversal?

```
BSONDocument: {
  v: {
    1.0: {
      2013: {
        9: {
          9: {
            l: BSONInteger(0),
            s: BSONInteger(8)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The second question is:
I find a document in DB with the following filter:

```
BSONDocument(
"_id" -> 0,
"v.1.0.2013.9.9.l" -> 1)
```

But it seems like instead of extracting just these values "_id" & "l" it extracts the whole document. When I do BSONDocument.pretty(foundDoc) I see the whole document, not just "l" value that I have requested. Please clarify if it is even worth specifying fields I am interested in if it always downloads the whole document.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should not use dotted keys (like you do in `1.0`).

Comment: They are supported by MongoDB, so I suppose I am free to use. However I understand that ideally I should not interfere with nested structuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like according to the sources it is not supported in reactivemongo. So I have created a quick helper:

```
def getAsByPath[T](path: String, doc: BSONDocument)
       (implicit reader: BSONReader[_ <: BSONValue, T]): Option[T] = {
  val pathChunks = path.split('.')
  var pathIndex = 0
  var curDoc: Option[BSONDocument] = Some(doc)
  var currentChunk = ""

  while(pathIndex != pathChunks.size) {
    currentChunk += pathChunks(pathIndex)

    // If this is the last chunk it must be a value
    // and if previous Doc is valid let's get it
    if (pathIndex == pathChunks.size - 1 && curDoc != None)
      return curDoc.get.getAs[T](currentChunk)

    val tmpDoc = curDoc.get.getAs[BSONDocument](currentChunk)
    if (tmpDoc != None) {
      currentChunk = ""
      curDoc = tmpDoc
    } else {
      // We need to support this as sometimes doc ID 
      // contain dots, for example "1.0"
      currentChunk += "."
    }

    pathIndex += 1
  }

  None
}
```

However my second question is still valid. If someone knows please let me know.

Comment: You're right, it does not exist yet in ReactiveMongo. It may be an interesting feature actually.

Comment: You are free to use my code snippet :) I find the library very performant and interesting, so glad to contribute.